# "no godep, using go get instead" even though I ran "go get github.com/tools/godep"

Tags: build, go

I am trying to build [syncthing](http://syncthing.net/):

```
$ ./build.sh 
Warning: no godep, using "go get" instead.
Try "go get github.com/tools/godep".
```

Even though it is only a warning, I would like to make it disappear.
As suggested by the message, I ran:

```
go get github.com/tools/godep
```

But even after doing so, the same error appears.
My `$GOPATH/bin` contains an executable called `godep`.

How to fix this warning?

*Ubuntu 2013.10 go version go1.1.2 linux/amd64*

UPDATE: I just realized that this warning is generated by build.sh itself, so the problem might be more localized than I thought.

Answer (score 6):

The [problem](https://github.com/calmh/syncthing/issues/134) was that I had not included `$GOPATH/bin` in my `$PATH`:

```
export PATH="${PATH}:${GOPATH}/bin"
```

That made the warning disappear.